# hover additional information with Shiny & ggplotly

Tags: r, shiny, plotly, ggplotly

I have been surfing around this site for answers to my problem with Shiny and Plotly (ggplotly) but none of these has been enough. I'm trying to customize hover boxtext of my ggplotly. I would to include more variables on that boxtext when you put your mouse over any point of my plot.

I have trying with this this solution
[Any way to display data frame information besides x and y on hover with shiny/ggplot?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45612335/any-way-to-display-data-frame-information-besides-x-and-y-on-hover-with-shiny-gg)
 and this one: [Shiny: Interactive ggplot with Vertical Line and Data Labels at Mouse Hover Point](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42104031/shiny-interactive-ggplot-with-vertical-line-and-data-labels-at-mouse-hover-poin?rq=1)

Without any successful result

I'm working trying to create visualization for football data, I have this huge df which has the followings variables:

```
     [1] "ID"              "Nombre"          "Apellido"        "Rol"            
 [5] "Tecnica"         "Club"            "Competicion"     "Nacionalidad"   
 [9] "PrimerToque"     "Dribbling"       "Versatilidad"    "Pases"          
[13] "Centros"         "Remate"          "TiroLibre"       "Cabezazo"       
[17] "TiroLejano"      "SaqueLateral"    "Marcaje"         "Penales"        
[21] "Tacle"           "Corner"          "Aceleracion"     "Stamina"        
[25] "Fuerza"          "Agilidad"        "Balance"         "TendenciaLesion"
[29] "Salto"           "FormaNatural"    "Velocidad"       "FechaNacimiento"
[33] "AnoNacimiento"   "CA"              "PA"              "RepHome"        
[37] "RepActual"       "RepMundial"      "Consistencia"    "Altura"         
[41] "Peso"            "Posicion"
```

this is my **ui** file

```
library("shiny")
library("shinythemes")
library("shinyWidgets")
library("shinydashboard")
library("leaflet")
library("ggplot2")
library("dplyr")
library("ggrepel")
library("plotly")

ui <- shinyUI(fluidPage(

  # Application title
  titlePanel("Graph"),       

  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(
      selectizeInput("Atributo1",  #xaxis 
                     label = "AtributoX",
                     choices = c("Centros", "Pases", "PrimerToque", "Remate", "Tecnica","Dribbling","TiroLejano",
                                 "TiroLibre", "SaqueLateral","Penales", "Corner" ,"Cabezazo", "Salto", "Aceleracion",
                                 "Stamina", "Fuerza","Agilidad","Balance","TendenciaLesion","FormaNatural","Velocidad", 
                                 "Marcaje", "Tacle","Consistencia", "Versatilidad", "CA", "RepHome"), selected ="CA"),
      selectizeInput("Atributo2",  #yaxis 
                     label = "AtributoY",
                     choices = c("Centros", "Pases", "PrimerToque", "Remate", "Tecnica","Dribbling","TiroLejano",
                                 "TiroLibre", "SaqueLateral","Penales", "Corner" ,"Cabezazo", "Salto", "Aceleracion",
                                 "Stamina", "Fuerza","Agilidad","Balance","TendenciaLesion","FormaNatural","Velocidad", 
                                 "Marcaje", "Tacle","Consistencia", "Versatilidad", "CA", "RepHome")),

      sliderInput("numero", "Numero de Jugadores a Mostrar:",
                  value = 10, min = 1, max = 50, round = TRUE, dragRange = FALSE),
      numericInput("Edad1", "Edad:", 42, value = 17),
      numericInput("Edad2", "Edad:", 42),

      sliderTextInput("Posicion","Posicion" , 
                      choices = c("GK","DL","DR","DC","DM","MC","ML","MR","AMC", "ST"), 
                      selected = c("MC"), #incase you want all values by default 
                      animate = FALSE, grid = FALSE, 
                      hide_min_max = FALSE, from_fixed = FALSE,
                      to_fixed = FALSE, from_min = NULL, from_max = NULL, to_min = NULL,
                      to_max = NULL, force_edges = FALSE, width = NULL, pre = NULL,
                      post = NULL, dragRange = TRUE),
      radioButtons("Color", label = "Color Por:",
                   choices = list("Club" = "Club", "Division" = "Competicion"), 
                   selected = "Club")
    ),          

    mainPanel(

      plotlyOutput("distPlot")
    )
  )
))
```

and my **server** file

```
server <- shinyServer(function(input, output) {

  output$distPlot <- renderPlotly({ #Plot tipo Plotly

    n <- input$numero
    if (is.null(n)) {
      n <- 1
    }

    dfjoin <- readRDS("dfjoin.rds")

    a <- reactive({
    dfjoin %>% filter(Posicion == input$Posicion) %>% filter(FechaNacimiento >= input$Edad1 & FechaNacimiento <= input$Edad2) %>% top_n(n, CA)
    })

    p <- ggplot(a(), aes_string(x = input$Atributo1, y = input$Atributo2, 
                              label = "Apellido", colour = input$Color)) + 
      geom_text(position=position_jitter(h=1,w=1), check_overlap = TRUE) +
      labs(colour= input$Color, title= paste("Grafico", input$Atributo1, "/",  input$Atributo2, sep =" ")) +
      theme(legend.position = "none")

    p <- ggplotly(p)

    print(p)
  })
})
```

Currently Im getting only default hover information, which is Label, X axis, Y axis and colour. I would like to customize and include another variables as put First Name and Last Name. Which would be something like: paste(Nombre,Apellido, sep = " ")

I tried that line inside Tooltip:

```
$ggplotly(p, Tooltip = paste(Nombre,Apellido, sep = " "))
```

but didnt worked neither.

as a tip: in spanish: 
Nombre = First Name
Apellido: Last Name

[image]

Comment: Use the `text` aesthetic. See here for an example: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54572843/modify-tooltip-info-of-a-plotly-graph-created-via-ggplotly/54573436#54573436

Comment: Finally I changed my ggplot code to plotly, it gives much more discretionality changing hover info.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've been doing that this way:

https://github.com/Bustami/DatoFutbol/blob/master/libertadores2019/shiny-app/server.R

Basically create a new column with all your text of interest (calling variables choosed by user) with HTML syntax and then use it with the "label" parameter inside ggplot and "tooltip" inside ggplotly.